# Can you reverse geocode multiple coordinates using a single request URL with Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode, google-geocoder

Is it possible to request multiple coordinates to be reverse-geocoded using a single request URL with Google Maps?

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53,-1.6&latlng=52,1.2&latlng=23,-2.9&sensor=false
```

Where I pass three different coordinates to be geocoded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all "Is it possible to..." questions is "What happens when you do that?"

**No.** This is not an option.